# "How to Format" sidebar overlaps footer

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

I just found it now. It is really doesn't matter the back end but it is OK to fix this.

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least to offer you the courtesy of something more than merely [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), and for those who abhor the effort of clicking on a link (as provided by @Qantas 94 Heavy), it seems that this was [raised on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel) (maybe you were supposed to realise that despite differences between sites, SO in particular, it would be considered a network issue - or rather a network non-issue) where Community Manager Pops did respond:

> We think that sidebar is pretty important, and want it to remain visible. The footer, on the other hand, isn't that important, and can always be accessed again with a bit of scrolling up. It's not worth the time to tweak the page so that it's only scrollable until the point of overlap.