# Stack Overflow Election page bug

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

There's a CSS/designing bug as I have observed at the moderator election page:

[image: Content in the right hand column overlaps the footer when scrolled to the bottom of the page.]

Comment: Why is that a bug? You scrolled down far enough to put those boxes in the footer, which has a completely different background. For those titles to be visible on both backgrounds, they'd have to be something like red...

Comment: Similar *bug* that is [status-declined](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266747/how-to-format-sidebar-overlaps-footer)

Comment: By the way, was posting a screen-shot of your actual votes intentional?

Comment: @Tunaki my intention was not to show to whom I voted for but it's more important for me to report the bug