# "Similar Question" sidebar z-index issue

Tags: bug, status-completed

When formulating a new question, if you scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page, the "Similar Question" sticky sidebar sits above the footer, but below the footer text. I realize that these [sidebars are intended to cover the footer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266747/how-to-format-sidebar-overlaps-footer), but the footer text should not cover the sidebar.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How to Format" sidebar overlaps footer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266747/how-to-format-sidebar-overlaps-footer), https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318443/right-menu-in-editing-help-page-overlaps-the-footer

Comment: @CodyGray You do realize the asker explicitly linked to that question, and mentioned that this one is different because the footer text is overlapping the sidebar, right? That issue is *not* part of the questions you linked, and it's not intended behavior.

Comment: Variations on this bug have been reported *numerous* times, both here and the global Meta. They have been completely ignored. Obviously this isn't important to anyone on the team. If they want to deal with it, they can look at and answer any of the multiple duplicates. I don't see a compelling reason to have this open; none of us can do anything about it.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, you can't do anything about it. The SE team can, though, and since this is clearly a different bug, closing it as a duplicate makes zero sense. The SE team has said they don't care that the sidebar overlaps the footer; they have not said they don't care if the sidebar and the footer are involved in z-fighting. If you have found a question where the SE team indicates that *this bug*, and not a closely related one, isn't an issue, then close as a dupe of that.

Comment: sigh...this is NOT a dupe. Even if SE team itself will say it is, it's not.

Comment: @Cody this one is different. Its a recent z-index bug, probably someone moved some cheese in CSS, failed to test, and that's the result. It can be easily fixed, if just anyone from the design team will bother to take a look. I do not expect this to happen of course, but who knows... and just in case, we should have this report open, not closed.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks again for reporting - it is now fixed on production.